# Show how to assume any matrix is upper triangular, and the concept of a basis in matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

How can you show that any given matrix can be assumed to be upper triangular? And what does the concept of a basis have to do with upper triangular matrices (or matrices in general)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A matrix represents a linear map with respect to a particular basis. I.e. if you have a vector space, and you transform it to a different vector space using a linear map, there is a correspondence between bases of the domain and co-domain of the map, and matrices. In particular, any $n\times n$ matrix can be 'viewed' as a linear map from an n-dimensional vector space to itself, transforming the standard basis (by scaling, rotating or shearing them).

An endomorphism is 'triangulable' (i.e. similar to a triangular matrix, or the linear map it represents is represented by a triangular matrix) iff its characteristic polynomial  can be written as a product of linear factors- not necessarily distinct. So in an algebraically closed field such as $\mathbb{C}$, every matrix is similar to a triangular matrix.